# Custom Android.Gms.Maps.Model.TileProvider issue with Constructor Arguments

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Android project and I am trying to create a Custom TileProvider to use offline maps from mbtiles sqlite database and found an example that does what i want to do here https://github.com/antoniocarlon/MapUtils however this example is done in java so I started creating my own based on the above code but in Xamarin.Android in c#.

So i have created a Class MBTilesProvider that inherits from Android.Gms.Maps.Model.TileProvider however the  : base(width, height) shows an error that 'TileProvider' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments. I know that error is pretty self explanatory but I can't seem to find any documentation around what the constructor arguments are for TileProvider ? If I remove the :base from my class I get the error message that 'TileProvider' does not contain a constructor that contains 0 arguments.

```
public class MBTilesProvider : TileProvider
{
    private int _width;
    private int _height;

    public MBTilesProvider(int width, int height) : base(width, height)
    {
        this._width = width;
        this._height = height;
    }

    public Tile GetTile(int x, int y, int zoom)
    {
        y = tms2gmaps(y, zoom);

        byte[] bitmap = RetreiveImage(x, y, zoom);

        Tile tile = new Tile(_width, _height, bitmap);

        return tile;
    }

    private byte[] RetreiveImage(int x, int y, int zoom)
    {
        byte[] image = null;

        if(zoom > 0)
        {
            image = ReadImageFromDB(x, y, zoom);

            if (image == null)
            {
                image = Crop(RetreiveImage(x / 2, y / 2, zoom - 1), x, y);
            }

            return image;
        }  
        else
        {
            return image;
        }
    }

    private byte[] ReadImageFromDB(int x, int y, int zoom)
    {
        DataClient.MBTilesClient mBTilesClient = new DataClient.MBTilesClient();
        return mBTilesClient.GetTile(x, y, zoom);
    }

    private int tms2gmaps(int y, int zoom)
    {
        int ymax = 1 << zoom;
        return ymax - y - 1;
    }

    private byte[] Crop(byte[] image, int x, int y)
    {
        byte[] output = image;

        if (image == null)
        {
            return output;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(image, 0, image.Length);
        bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap,
            x % 2 == 0 ? 0 : bitmap.Width / 2,
            y % 2 == 0 ? bitmap.Height / 2 : 0,
            bitmap.Width,
            bitmap.Height
            );

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
        bitmap.Recycle();
        output = stream.ToArray();

        return output;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Eddie

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ITileProvider` interface instead of the `TileProvider` abstract class. Then you won't have issues with constructors.

`public class MBTilesProvider : Java.Lang.Object, ITileProvider`

I don't know why Xamarin creates both or how the abstract class should be used. I had the same issue, but this solved it for me. The Java.Lang.Object is so you don't have to override the Handle and Dispose methods.